# Customizing System Form in Sap business one 9.1

Tags: sapb1

I am trying to  get System Form in visual studio .But its not showing SAP business one system forms. want to add custom field to sales order.

**How in can i get sales order form in visual studio using Add System forms**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Make sure to open the Sales Order Form inside Sap business one. Then follow up the steps to add system form for the visual studio solution. Sales order form will be visible on the "Add System Form" window, where you need to select and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

I've been modifying system forms in 9.0. Generally you have to capture the FORM_LOAD event so that you can detect the new form being opened, then you have to amend the form.

You can amend the forms either by adding controls into the items collection on the form object:

```
oForm.Items.Add(...)
```

Or you can create an XML structure that can be passed to SBO_Application.LoadBatchActions.

If you add a breakpoint after getting a reference to the form, you can grab the XML as a reference using oForm.GetAsXML in the watch window - just snip out the XML and view it in an editor.

If you have Business One Studio, you can design forms - not much use for system forms, but if you export as an SRF file, you'll be able to alter the XML and run it over the top of the System Form using LoadBatchActions.

I Hope that this gives you some ideas.

Mark

Comment: This is correct. The key is that because you're working with a system form, you need to "programmatically" add new UI components/controls to it, you won't be able to edit/add components to the form in a "windows forms" like  manner like you would if you were creating your own stand-alone form with the screen-painter or Business One Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the page, go to SAP B1 and click which form you want. Then it will appear there.